# android/java use pass class object to onClickListener

Tags: java, android

I was wondering if it is possible to use Object.getClass() to make a new object with that class, without knowing which class it's gonna be. This probably sounds confusing, so a little example:

I have two classes `Calc1` and `Calc2`, both have a method `calculate()` but they return different results (for instance `public int calculate() {return a*b;}` and `public int calculate() {return a/b;}`). Now i want to access these classes on a button click, but I only want to write one `onClick()` method, and not one for each class. So, whether the object is of type `Calc1` or `Calc2`, the `onClick()` method should get the right one. I have a controller in which I store the object:

```
public class Controller {

    Object activeClass;

    public Controller(){}

    public void setActiveClass (Object active){
        this.activeClass = active;
    }

    public Object getActiveClass(){
        return this.activeClass;
    }

}
```

And each class has a method to pass the obeject (itself) to the controller:

```
public class Calc1 extends AppCompatActivity implements Calculate{

    int a;
    int b;
    private Controller controller;

    private EditText editA;
    private EditText editB;

    public Calc1 (int a, int b){
        editA = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editA);
        editB = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editB);
        controller = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("controller");
        setController(controller);
        controller.setActiveLayout(this);
    }

    private void setController (Controller c){
        this.controller = c;
    }

    public Object getController(){
        return this.controller;
    }

    private void setA(){
        this.a = Integer.parseInt(editA.getText().toString());
    }

    public int getA(){
        return this.a;
    }

    private void setB(){
        this.b = Integer.parseInt(editB.getText().toString());;
    }

    public int getB(){
        return this.b;
    }

    public int calculate(){
        setA();
        setB();
        return getA()*getB();
    }
}
```

So now for the button onClick method I was hoping I could do something like this:

```
public class MyListener implements View.OnClickListener {

    Object activeObject;

    public MyListener(Object o){
        this.activeObject = o;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        this.activeObject.calculate();
    }
}
```

And also, here's the Main class and the Button class:

```
public class Main extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button calc1;
    private Button calc2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final Controller controller = new Controller();

        calc1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        calc1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Main.this, Calc1.class);
                intent.putExtra("controller", (Parcelable) controller);
                startActivity(intent);

                Intent intentBtn = new Intent(Main.this, ButtonClass.class);
                intent.putExtra("controller", (Parcelable) controller);
                startActivity(intentBtn);
            }
        });

        calc2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        calc2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Main.this, Calc2.class);
                intent.putExtra("controller", (Parcelable)controller);
                startActivity(intent);

                Intent intentBtn = new Intent(Main.this, ButtonClass.class);
                intent.putExtra("controller", (Parcelable) controller);
                startActivity(intentBtn);
            }
        });
    }
}



    public class ButtonClass extends AppCompatActivity {

        public Button calculate;
        public Controller controller;

        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            controller = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("controller");
            setController(controller);

            calculate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.calculateButton);
            calculate.setOnClickListener(new MyListener(controller.getActiveLayout()));
        }
        private void setController(Controller c) {
            this.controller = c;
        }
    }
```

but of course this doesn't work. My question: In case you even understand what I'm trying to do (I feel like I'm very bad at explaining ;)), is there a way to do this, or something like that?

basically, i want to just have one, easy, simple button onClick method, instead of having a switch case or if() else loop that goes through every possible case. For only two classes Calc1 and Calc2 this might not be a problem, but I'm actually trying to do something like this for over 15 classes, and then it gets a little too chaotic i feel.

Thanks for reading :)

EDIT: So I changed the code snippets to the complete code and added the interface code that I just made. The thing is if  use an interface, I still don't know how my `onClick()` method is supposed to know what kind of object it has.

I added an interface:

```
public interface Calculate {

    public int calculate();

}
```

and implemented it: see above

Comment: Have you heard of interfaces? Have an interface proclaim a method called  `calculate` and have both the classes implement it.

Comment: Yes, I tried that, but it didn't work either. I probably didn't do it right. I will try again and let you know if it works, otherwise I might need help ;)

Comment: You probably didn't. :) Can you post the code of that attempt so we can see what's wrong with it?

Comment: Vucko - I don't know if you saw it, but I added the code in my original post (see "EDIT"):)

Comment: Try using a Factory pattern to decide which object to create. But you can't avoid the if/else

Comment: Instead of having a field of the type ```Object``` in your ```Controller```, change it to the type ```Calculate```, so you can call ```.calculate()``` on it.

Comment: Thank you Jorn Vernee! I think this is exactly what I did wrong :)